# The WP_Widget class seems to run many times on a page load

Tags: widgets, performance

I have a plugin that extends the `WP_Widget` class. It's very similar to [this example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) in the Codex:

```
class My_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    /**
     * Sets up the widgets name etc
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array( 
            'classname' => 'my_widget',
            'description' => 'My Widget is awesome',
        );
        parent::__construct( 'my_widget', 'My Widget', $widget_ops );
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the content of the widget
     *
     * @param array $args
     * @param array $instance
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        // outputs the content of the widget
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the options form on admin
     *
     * @param array $instance The widget options
     */
    public function form( $instance ) {
        // outputs the options form on admin
    }

    /**
     * Processing widget options on save
     *
     * @param array $new_instance The new options
     * @param array $old_instance The previous options
     */
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        // processes widget options to be saved
    }
}
```

In my plugin, I have a widget method as well:

`public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    error_log('run widget');
}`

I've noticed that when I load a front end page (such as the homepage, or a post), that error log runs anywhere between 16 and 21 times, depending on the theme (I've tried the Twenty Seventeen, Twenty Sixteen, and a basic Underscores theme for comparison.

I wanted to see if this was normal, so I put a similar `error_log` into the `widget` method of the core `/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-archives.php` (this is line 45 of that file, at least in WordPress 4.7.2). It runs just as many times on a front end page load. When both methods are logging, the log entries for each mix together rather than running in succession.

I've been trying to figure out if this is expected behavior, if it is configurable, and/or any performance implications it might have. I can cache the results of my method, so maybe it is not a problem for this case, but I'd like to understand it better.

Comment: I assume that every time an instance of `WP_Widget` is made (e.g when widgets are initialized), your `widget` method is executed.

Comment: That's while loading the front-end page where the widget is displayed? Or while viewing a back-end (admin) page?

Comment: @MacPrawn yes, front-end. I'll edit to indicate that.

Comment: @SamuelElh does that mean each instance of `WP_Widget` would execute all the other instances that many times?

Comment: Hmm - logs only once for me, using TwentySeventeen... Could it be your theme or another plugin doing this? Any calls to the function `the_widget` in your code base?

Comment: Weird. Maybe I need a clean install. I only find results for `the_widget` in the core `wp-includes/widgets.php` file, although it is also in some inactive themes.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, 'widget' method is not a constructor to have that. I have tried exactly the same as you and it logs error only once. I assume some plugin is involved with this so try a fresh install with no plugins or search through your files with sublime Text (ctrl+shift+f) or `grep -R "\->widget("` in the root of your install.

Comment: Well, it is as you both say: when I start over with a vanilla wordpress and put in just my plugin without others, it only runs once. Many thanks.

Comment: It all boils down to the [HTTPS Mixed Content Detector plugin](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/https-mixed-content-detector/), which is a bit old now.